# android studio on 4k resolution

Tags: windows, windows-10, android-studio, 4k-resolution

My monitor is 4k and I am running Windows 10. Android studio on my monitor is very small:

[image: android studio on 4k image]

I have tried [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot) but it did not work.

I looked at Windows 10 high DPI scaling override but all items are disabled.

[image: High DPI image]

How can I use Android studio on 4k resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is based on the old IntelliJ IDEA platform, so probably does not
adapt well to hi-res monitors.

Some advice :

- Find the executable, maybe named `studio64.exe`, right-click it and choose Properties,
  in the Compatibility tab click "Change high DPI settings", check
  "Ovsrride high DPI scaling behavior" and choose in the drop-box "System (Enhanced)",
  then click OK.
- Set the 4k Monitor as the primary one and log out and back in.
- A long shot : Use regedit to navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\studio64.exe` (if the exe name is correct and such a key exists),
  create a DWORD key named `dpiAwareness` and try it with the values of `1` or `0`.

Undo advice which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Type Make everything bigger into search bar on Windows 10, you should get the value under Display (alternatively found under the control panel). You just have to use the slider. I had the same issue and found that there was already a recommended value next to make everything bigger, which apparently scales text with various apps including Android Studio.

[Type Make everything bigger into search bar on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XChE.png)